# How can I dynamically get model name mvc 4 c#4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, model

Using VS2012 and MVC4, how can I obtain the current model's name?

I want to dynamically name some variables using the model name itself.  Is there a way? I have found controllers and actions, but not any model info, yet.

Comment: I'm trying to pull it on the Model and write the variables there.  Last resort, I'd like to pull the info in on the controller.  Admitted Newb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
@model.GetType().Name
```

As @Rowan Freeman notes in the comment below, you can also do this from the model itself:

```
GetType().Name; // or this.GetType().Name;
```

... or this from a controller:

```
var model = new MyCustomViewModel();
var modelName = model.GetType().Name;
```

Comment: No I haven't, but I'm trying to get it from the model itself, or the controller if I have to do that.  I'd prefer to pull the name in the model and write the variables there.

Comment: While inside the model use `GetType().Name`.